# How to decode a Google App Engine entity Key path str in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine, an entity has a Key.  A key can be made from a path, in which case str(key) is an opaque hex string.  Example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
foo = db.Key.from_path(u'foo', u'bar', _app=u'baz')
print foo
```

gives

```
agNiYXpyDAsSA2ZvbyIDYmFyDA
```

if you set up the right paths to run the code.

So, how can one take the hex string and get the path back?  I thought the answer would be in [Key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html) or [entity group](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html) docs, but I can't see it.

Comment: You can get the Key back using the constructor - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key. I'm not sure how to get the path back from the Key though.

Comment: You may use this tool for viewing a specific key : http://datastore-key.appspot.com/ . It also works as a service with JSON output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

k = db.Key('agNiYXpyDAsSA2ZvbyIDYmFyDA')
_app = k.app()
path = []
while k is not None:
  path.append(k.id_or_name())
  path.append(k.kind())
  k = k.parent()
path.reverse()
print 'app=%r, path=%r' % (_app, path)
```

when run in a Development Console, this outputs:

```
app=u'baz', path=[u'foo', u'bar']
```

as requested.  A shorter alternative is to use the (unfortunately, I believe, undocumented) `to_path` method of `Key` instances:

```
k = db.Key('agNiYXpyDAsSA2ZvbyIDYmFyDA')
_app = k.app()
path = k.to_path()
print 'app=%r, path=%r' % (_app, path)
```

with the same results.  But the first, longer version relies only on documented methods.

Comment: Lack of documentation of .to_path() is a bug - it's definitely intended to be used externally. :)

Comment: It is certainly a lot easier than trying to manually decode it!

Comment: @Nick, I suspected that, but didn't really _know_!  So, tx for the info.  Fortunately, it looks like it's just going to be a fast-to-fix documentation bug.

Comment: Setup I used to test: export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/share/google_appengine/:/usr/local/share/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib (because I installed into /usr/local/share)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the `Key` object (which can be created by passing that opaque identifier to the constructor), use [`Key.to_path()`](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py#279) to get the path of a `Key` as a list.  For example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
opaque_id = 'agNiYXpyDAsSA2ZvbyIDYmFyDA'
path = db.Key(opaque_id).to_path()
```