# GAE-JAVA-JDO How to build a decoded entity key breadcrumb

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'd like to know how they did it in the edit page of the datastore viewer and any help would be much appreciate. Seems pretty simple but can't figure it out. Here's a screenshot to show exactly what I mean.[image: A decoded entity key]

Answer (score 3):

The `Key` class has a kind and (name or id), and also a `parent`, which will be null or another key.

Starting from the key for an entity, you can print the kind and the id, then look for the parent, print its kind and id, then look for its parent, print the kind and id, etc.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key

Comment: Hi Riley,

Thanks for your answer but sadly I knew all that already. As a String encoded Key is supposed to hold all the ancestors path information I though there might be a way to decode it and have the data to display such a breadcrumb in one go, without loop and request on the parent until it's null.
I thought Key.toString could help but I can even manage to import KeyFactory and Key on the client side. :(

Any other suggestion?

Comment: There probably is a way to decode it, but I don't think Google provides one.  I think you'll have to decode it on the server and pass back the separate parts.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, I will push my investigations further and let people know if I find a clean solution. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Apparently there is a way to do it. See the python answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151379/

Answer (score 1):

The string encoded Key does indeed contain the kind and id of itself and all its ancestors. There is no problem with looping server-side on the parent field until it is null (it's basically a string + objects manipulation, no query to the datastore is involved), to create the breadcrumb.

I don't know if it has been done client-side in JS, but it should be possible as it is basically a base64 encoding. See function `Encode()` in https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/datastore/key.go for the algorithm.

This online tool decodes and encode keys : http://datastore-key.appspot.com . It also works as a service with JSON output. The Go code server-side does not issue datastore queries.

Answer (score 0):

The Java answer is probably this:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#stringToKey(java.lang.String)

This gives you a `Key` from an encoded representation, which you can then query for kind, namespace, id, parent and appId, which allows similar processing than in the python answer mentioned in a comment above.

As an example, the following code fragment remaps a key that has one parent and comes originally from another GAE application:

```
  String key = "sflkjsadfliasjflkhsa"; // replace this by a real key

  // a not very elegant way to get the current app id
  String appId = KeyFactory.createKey("dummy", 1).getAppId();

  // here, the key is converted from an encoded String to a key object
  Key keyObj = KeyFactory.stringToKey(key);
  String oldAppId = keyObj.getAppId();

  // if the app id is different, we have to convert the key
  if (!appId.equals(oldAppId)) {
      // creeate a new key with parent having the correct app id
      Key parentKey = keyObj.getParent();
      Key newParentKey = KeyFactory.createKey(parentKey.getKind(), parentKey.getId());
      Key newKeyObj = KeyFactory.createKey(newParentKey, keyObj.getKind(), keyObj.getId());

      // convert the key back to a String replacing the original one
      String newKey = KeyFactory.keyToString(newKeyObj);

      // replace this by a call to your logger
      Log.warn(getClass(), "remapped key: appId: " + oldAppId + " -> " + appId + " oldKey: " + key + " -> " + newKey);

      key = newKey;
  }
```