# Memcache viewer in new GAE console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to delete a key from the memcache using the latest GAE console (https://console.developers.google.com/appengine/memcache).  I used to be able to do this with the old console but I can't figure out the new one.

Sometimes I manually edit an entity with the GAE console and afterwards I need to delete the entity from the memcache so that my app uses the latest data.  I know the entity is in the memcache since the old data is being served, but I can't find it with the memcache viewer.

Here is the new memcache console:

[image: memcache console]

I leave Namespace blank because I don't use them.

I select Python String for the key type since I am using Python.

For the key, I've tried:

- Key('Election', 6254893018906624)
- aglzfm9wYXZvdGVyFQsSCEVsZWN0aW9uGICAgKSsmY4LDA
- NDB9:aglzfm9wYXZvdGVyFQsSCEVsZWN0aW9uGICAgKSsmY4LDA

but none of them work.

Clicking the "Show all keys" link just produces a blank screen.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041248/how-to-clear-cache-for-specific-model-in-ndb

Comment: @marcadian, no actually, not even close other than the fact they both relate to memcache.

Comment: If you want to clear our stale data you can always flush the whole memcache but i can understand if you don't want to do that. I experience the same with the *Show all keys*, so that seems "normal". It will be exceptionally difficult (impossible) to tell you what your keys should look like. Quite possibly it is the encoded entity id (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151379/how-to-decode-a-google-app-engine-entity-key-path-str-in-python) when you supply the full path, but that is pure speculation because it depends on what library you use to cache your datastore entities.

Comment: I think my second attempt above is the encoded id...  Good to know that others are having trouble with this as well...

Comment: did you solve this? I can't seem to be able to use the find key either...

Comment: @Konstantine, I haven't tried since then.  My solution is to edit entities using remote_api_shell.py because this will cause memcache to be updated.  I now never edit entities from the console.

Comment: It would be nice if someone from the Google Cloud Platform team told us what Memcache keys for Datastore entities look like. This shouldn't be a secret...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure for Python, but for Java, with Objectify, I have used this many times:

Namespace: ObjectifyCache

Key type: Java String

Key: aglzfm9wYXZvdGVyFQsSCEVsZWN0aW9uGICAgKSsmY4LDA (from your data)